# why have most of the files in a dreamweaver site been put into a directory called 'upload'?

Tags: upload, ftp, templates, dreamweaver

I cleaned up someone's style sheet for a Dreamweaver site, by editing the css directly, and now the secretary is having trouble using her old template.

Most of the files in her site reside in subdirectories of the 'upload' directory.  For example, I would have expected to see the stylesheet in
    ../assets/css/ etc.
but in fact I'm finding it in
    ../upload/assets/css/ etc.

In addition to assets, I am also finding Templates and images as subdirectories of 'upload'.

Do you know why this 'upload' directory was used?

I am considering two possible approaches.

(1) Make sure everything needed is in ../upload/ and remove the subdirectories that are directly in the root directory

(2) Edit the template to remove all references to ../upload/

Note that (2) appeals to me because the file structure will be simpler; but I wonder if the client has some sort of extension in her Dreamweaver that causes everything she ftp's to be put into the 'upload' directory.

Note that so far I have copied my cleaned up css file over to ../upload/assets/ as a short-term solution.  But they want to be able to make changes to their template, and add new pages, on their own in future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely problem is how she has her FTP remote settings specified. It appears that it now points to the upload folder rather than the web root. Or, it could be that her FTP user account is tied to the upload folder rather than the web root.